# illustrator crashes on open preferences

Tags: windows, crash, adobe-illustrator

My Illustrator (CS3, windows xp sp3) crashes when I select Edit...Preferences. This is a new error and has only started to happen recently. I can only guess my preferences have somehow become corrupted? Has anyone encountered this or can anyone suggest a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer here (http://indesignsecrets.com/rebuilding-indesign-preferences.php). I held down Ctrl+Alt+Shift when starting Illustrator. This reset my preferences and (to my surprise) solved the problem.